# Installed SSL certificate, but when I goto my domain I have to include https:// before the URL

Tags: apache, ssl, https

So I've been messing around with Apache, and I bought a SSL certificate. I finally got it installed, but now when I goto my domain with the URL (leethecoder.com) I assume it's trying to use HTTP? And my server, of course, with a SSL certificate is not listening on port 80. But, if I include https:// before the URL (https://leethecoder.com), it works. Is there a way I can make the server force the basic URL (leethecoder.com) goto port 443?

This is my current `/sites-enabled/` configuration file.

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.leethecoder.com
    ServerAlias www.leethecoder.com leethecoder.com
    Options -Indexes
    DocumentRoot /var/www/leethecoder.com/public_html/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/leethecoder_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/sslkey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/foobundle.ca-bundle
    ErrorLog /var/www/leethecoder.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: You will also have to listen on port 80 and redirect all traffic from there to HTTPS.

Comment: Okay, so I assume it would be on the virtual host listening on port 80. I'll be able to actually test it out in a few.

Comment: Please add SSLProtocol and a correct SSLCipherSuite, and then check with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, **this** is "properly" ([you're currently an A-](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=leethecoder.com), the below might help to get an A+):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName leethecoder.com
  ServerAlias *.leethecoder.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ErrorLog /var/www/leethecoder.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  RedirectPermanent / https://leethecoder.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.leethecoder.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite "-ALL EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+AES EECDH+aRSA+AES EDH+aRSA+AES RSA+3DES"
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/leethecoder_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/sslkey.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/foobundle.ca-bundle
  ErrorLog /var/www/leethecoder.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  RedirectPermanent / https://leethecoder.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName leethecoder.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  ErrorLog /var/www/leethecoder.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/leethecoder.com/public_html
  <Directory /var/www/leethecoder.com/public_html/>
    Allow From All
  </Directory>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite "-ALL EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+AES EECDH+aRSA+AES EDH+aRSA+AES RSA+3DES"
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/leethecoder_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/sslkey.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/leethecoder.com/foobundle.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

This is, of course, assuming that your variables are valid, you prefer the https without the www, and that you're OK for your clients to use that cipher suite. Also, that you've enabled the site, and disabled any other conflicting sites.

Comment: Really appreciate that. Are the extra variables for security or is it just more professional to have all that can be applied?

Comment: I actually did not include any professional variables (i.e. not essential for security) or fun extension stuff etc. The above is bare minimum for security.

Comment: You're currently an A-, which is actually not that bad at all, so if you're just messing around, you don't really have to do anything. I just had to answer as I felt uneasy with the accepted answer with the words "proper way" and "secure way"...

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I got it to work, I really appreciate the help. I did have a side question though - how would I go about creating a subdomain that will **not use** a SSL cert.? Since it's redirecting all traffic on port 80 to port 443.

Comment: Well, if you have already configured the subdomain, then all it is is another virtualhost on port 80 (ServerName will be the FQN)... buuuut have you configured the sub to route to your IP?

Comment: Yeah, my DNS record has the subdomain pointing to my server. So would I just define another virtual host on port 80 that has the ServerName and ServerAlias set to the subdomain?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes, but not the ServerAlias *.leethecoder.com. See that's a catch all. So have that in the second VH, but the first with the subdomain, just have without any alias.

Comment: Great! Happy to help, especially someone who listens and responds! Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it -- secure way -- is to use the apache virtual host redirect:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:443="">
ServerName www.example.com
# ... SSL configuration goes here
</virtualhost>
```

Or you need to use mod_rewrite to return an HTTP_RESPONSE 301 for redirect to your HTTPS site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
```

Also you need to listen port 80.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: "Do it" where exactly…?

Comment: With a virtual host listening on port 80 or should I include that in my virtual host listening on port 443?